# Android 11 / Foreground services как отключить уведомление / альтернатива Foreground services

Tags: java, android

Я использую Foreground services (В нем идет постоянное подключение через вебсокеты).
Но Foreground services создает уведомления, можноли его убрать на андроид 11? (находил костыли но они не работают на api 30).

Или есть альтернатива Foreground services ?

Comment: 99,(9)% вероятности ничего сделать нельзя, т.к. так уж система задумана. Возможно, если вы договоритесь напрямую с google/производителями каждого девайса, они на уровне прошивки добавят ваше приложение в исключения. Так сделано, по идее, для GMS - чтобы пуши работали и прочий сбор инфе о юзере.

Comment: У телеграма же нет уведомления и при этом он все время работает в фоне...Какие есть альтернативы?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, телеграм использует пуши и/или периодические опросы сервера на предмет новых сообщений. Если у вас есть другая информация - поделитесь. Возможно, в исходниках телеграма есть ответ на этот вопрос.

Comment: Вот пуши в исходниках телеграмма: https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram/blob/ca13bc972dda0498b8ffb40276423a49325cd26d/TMessagesProj/src/main/java/org/telegram/messenger/GcmPushListenerService.java Никакой магии, самый обычный FCM